# cardinality of the ring $\frac {Z[i]}{(2+i)^3} $

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to check the cardinality of $\frac {Z[i]}{(2+i)^3} $  .
I know that this ring is not integral domain. I can't use chinese remainder theorem directly.
I tried using $\frac {Z[X]}{(X^2+1)}   \simeq Z[i] $ ; but could not proceed further .
Any help?

Comment: you are in a ring where $(2+i)^3=0$ that is $2=11i$, now try to identify this relation with the finite ring $\mathbb Z_n$

Comment: sorry, how do you create a relationship with Z_n? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, in $\mathbb Z[i]/(2+i)^3$, we have $2-11i=0$.

Squaring both sides, this gives $125=0$.

Natural guess is $\mathbb Z[i]/(2+i)^3$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{125}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Define $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z[i]/(2+i)^3$.

Since $11$ has inverse in all of the rings above, and since $11i=2$, we can solve for $i$ in the ring. So $f$ is surjective.

By above observation, $125\mathbb Z\in ker(f)$

For $n\in ker(f),f(n)=\left<2-11i\right>\implies n=(x+iy)(2-11i)=(2x+11y)+i(-11x+2y)\implies y=2^{-1}\cdot 11x$

Therefore $n=2x+11y=x\cdot 2^{-1}125\in125\mathbb Z$

So we established an isomorphism $\mathbb Z/\left<125\mathbb Z\right>\to\mathbb Z[i]/(2+i)^3$.

Comment: How are you defining f ?

Comment: how many $f$ can there be? what do you think?

Comment: well this is a good exercise that $f$ is unique, and this defines the characteristic of a ring.

Comment: ok yes . It's unique. I got it.